# Scaling MySQL (sharding): Tesora, ScaleArc, youtube/vitess or scalebase?

Tags: mysql, database, scalability, high-availability, vitess

Scaling MySQL (sharding): [Tesora](http://www.tesora.com/), [ScaleArc](http://www.scalearc.com/), [vitess](http://vitess.io/), [jetpants](https://github.com/tumblr/jetpants) , [MySQL Fabric](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/fabric/), [SpiderDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/spider-storage-engine-overview/) or [shardquery](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/shard-query/)? What are the differences between them and who stands out? Which one am I forgetting? Anybody with good experience on these?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Very few people truly need to shard. Are you having performance issues? What else have you tried to resolve them?

Comment: You missed MySQL Fabric, SpiderDB, shardquery

Comment: Firstly, this is an infrastructure question and as such belongs to ServerFault.  Secondly, OP did not provide any context so it should be closed either as too broad or as tool recommendation request. OP, please restate your question to be answerable within SO rules.